# How to track down which operation is low down the launching process?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

It takes a long duration of time for my App to be launched. How can I track down which operation causes this trouble?

Comment: Use instruments time profiling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to use the [Time Profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html) which is part of Instruments.

You can press <kbd>Cmd + I</kbd> to start profiling your application. Then select the Time Profiler.

[image]

This tool records how long each call takes and you can use it to narrow down which parts of your code are causing the biggest problems.

[image]

Double clicking an entry will show you the calls within that method and how long they each take

[image]

I find it useful to select these options in "Call Tree"

[image]